# How to escape JSON in an HTML string stored as a Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, escaping

I'm trying to parse a JSON string and I can't get it to work because of illegal chracters - which I cannot find...

Here is what I have:

```
make = function (el) {
    var config = el.getAttribute("data-config");
    console.log(config);
    var dyn = $.parseJSON(config)
    console.log(dyn);
}

var a= document.createElement("<a href='#' class='template' data-config=\"{'role':'button','iconpos':'left','icon':'star','corners':'false','shadow':'false', 'iconshadow':'false', 'theme':'a','class':'test', 'href':'index.html','text':'Star Icon', 'mini':'true', 'inline':'true'}\">Star Icon</a>");
console.log(a);
make(a);
```

I'm not really sure how to correctly unescape the JSON in my original string "a", so that it works.

**Question_:**
Which quotation marks do I need to escape to get this to work?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Ok. I figured it out using `Jquery` (I'd prefer Javascript-only though). This works:

```
make = function (el) {
    var config = el.attr("data-config");
        console.log(config);
    var dyn = $.parseJSON(config)
        console.log(dyn);
}

var c = $('<a href="#" class="template" data-config=\'{"role":"button","iconpos":"left","icon":"star","corners":"false","shadow":"false", "iconshadow":"false", "theme":"a","class":"test", "href":"index.html","text":"Star Icon", "mini":"true", "inline":"true"}\'>Star Icon</a>')
console.log(c);
make(c);
```

So escaping the start/end quotations of the JSON string seems to do the trick. The actual problem was that I can not use `document.createElement` with a full string. I can only create the element `document.createElement(a)` and then set `innerHTML`. Need to look into this some more.

If someone can tell me a Javascript-only way how to do this, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use this site to validate your json: http://jsonlint.com/  That will tell you if you have any illegal characters or incorrect markup

Comment: I think your single quotes need to be double quotes

Comment: I know Jsonlint. Problem is, it complains about the two wrapping quotation marks. Without them the JSON is correct, but the HTML syntax is wrong.

Comment: How about you create the element without JSON, and then just set the attribute afterwards? The DOM API should take care of the escaping. (Or rather, when using the DOM API, no escaping should be necessary.)

Comment: @wirey: trying that. Thanks

Comment: @millimoose: would be an option, but I'm getting a large HTML chunk like this with multiple elements using JSON config. So I cannot set it manually (only on the wrapping element)

Comment: @frequent here's a way you can do it with pure javascript [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/kKm7b/)

Answer (score 7):

[Strings and object keys in JSON must be **double** quoted.](http://json.org) Double quotes in attributes are not valid, so you'll need to [escape them with `&quot;`](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/MCDKL/).

Also, you probably want to use booleans `true`/`false` instead of strings `"true"`/`"false"`.

```
var a = document.createElement('<a href="#" class="template" data-config="{&quot;role&quot;:&quot;button&quot;,&quot;iconpos&quot;:&quot;left&quot;,&quot;icon&quot;:&quot;star&quot;,&quot;corners&quot;:false,&quot;shadow&quot;:false,&quot;iconshadow&quot;:false,&quot;theme&quot;:&quot;a&quot;,&quot;class&quot;:&quot;test&quot;, &quot;href&quot;:&quot;index.html&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Star Icon&quot;, &quot;mini&quot;:true,&quot;inline&quot;:true}\">Star Icon</a>');
```

Notice this is completely unreadable and [@millimoose's suggestion about just setting the attribute afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533382/how-to-escape-json-in-an-html-string-stored-as-a-javascript-variable/15533473#comment22005432_15533382) will make this much easier to deal with in the long run.

Comment: Ok. Didn't know that. Trying.